# I want to add div element with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was playing around jQuery and wanted to add `div` element with `append` but it doesn't seem to work, it does absolutely nothing when I click on `button`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main').on('click', '#btn', function() {
    var value = $('#main input').val();
    var html = '<div id="cont4><p>' + value + '</p></div>';
    $('#main').append(html);
  })
})
```

```css
#cont4 {
  width: 290px;
  height: 600px;
  background: rgb(30, 33, 33, 0.85);
  margin-top: 15vh;
  margin-left: 17vh;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: 0.35s;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #0c0921;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="cont1">
    <h1>Basic</h1>
    <p>Buy <span>Basic</span> packet and get:</p>
    <p>300 Minutes Talk</p>
    <p>500 SMS</p>
    <p>5GB NET<a href="google.com" class="ppp"> More info</a></p>
    <button>Buy Now !</button>
  </div>
  <input>asd
  <button id="btn">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too, and also *doesn't seem to work* isn't a scientific reason. Explain what's happening (or not).

Comment: Do you have any input in #main? Do you have #btn in #main?

Comment: Yes i've everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed double quotes for `id="cont4"` in this line, so use the below line in your js

`var html = '<div id="cont4"><p>' + value +'</p></div>';`

Working code here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main').on('click', '#btn', function() {
    var value = $('#main input').val();
    var html = '<div id="cont4"><p>' + value + '</p></div>';
    $('#main').append(html);
  })
})
```

```css
#cont4 {
  width: 290px;
  height: 600px;
  background: rgb(30, 33, 33, 0.85);
  margin-top: 15vh;
  margin-left: 17vh;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: 0.35s;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #0c0921;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="cont1">
    <h1>Basic</h1>
    <p>Buy <span>Basic</span> packet and get:</p>
    <p>300 Minutes Talk</p>
    <p>500 SMS</p>
    <p>5GB NET<a href="google.com" class="ppp"> More info</a></p>
    <button>Buy Now !</button>
  </div>
  <input>asd
  <button id="btn">add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo error in your code ;).
closing " is missing in your append function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main').on('click', '#btn', function() {
    var value = $('#main input').val();
    var html = '<div id="cont4"><p>' + value + '</p></div>';
    $('#main').append(html);
  })
})
```

```css
#main {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cont4 {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#btn {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"><input type="text"></input>This is the main container<button id="btn">Button</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `jQuery element` for `append` function.
Change this

```
'<div id="cont4"><p>' + value +'</p></div>'
```

to

```
 $('<div id="cont4"><p>' + value +'</p></div>');
```

that means you are creating a element from that string. then append that to another element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#main').on('click', '#btn', function(){
                var value = $('#main input').val();
                var html = $('<div id="cont4"><p>' + value +'</p></div>');
                $('#main').append(html);
            })
})
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.